# Java code doesn't fully work when triggered by timer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

I wrote a simple GUI which retrieves data from Excel spreadsheets and draws it on the Screen (together with a Special Color code).
The program itself works perfectly fine. But when I added a timer (swing/utils tried) to periodically update the Excel data (ie. reloading the data every 15 Seconds) a lot of data is missing on the Screen (blank Labels which should be filled with text, etc.)

I removed the timer -> worked perfectly again (but would of course require a program restart every once in a while - which I can't bear :D)
I added a button to try out manual data update -> works perfectly, but - meh - it should update periodically without someone having to klick a button

It seems that the timer function requires threads to be completed in a certain (very short) time period.

What would you suggest?

Code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

  .
  .
  .           
       }

  }, 100, 15000);
```

Comment: Can you please show your code ? It seems you required a scheduler and not a Timer. And it's 'Click' not 'Klick' :)

Comment: added above. yeah, i tried several methods but nothing really worked. i am really wondering why it does work perfectly when updating by a mouse click but not by a timer/Scheduler...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1):

The updates to your GUI must be done on the event thread. The MouseListener *is* executed on the event thread, but your timer's run() method is not. the GUI updating code inside your run() method should be done in another runnable that is passed to SwingUtilities.invokeLater().